# How to get last_inserted_id with laravel Request

Tags: php, laravel

I used the function below to insert my users data to database from a form.

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request, Users $user)
   {
      Users::create($request->all());
     echo $user->id;
   }
```

I tried to get the last inserted id but nothing is showing. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request, Users $user)
{
    $user = Users::create($request->all());
    echo $user->id;
}
```

Or

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    $user = new Users($request->all());
    $user->save($user);
    echo $user->id;
}
```